# Jmeter: Difference between JTL file and Output file in Listeners

Tags: configuration, jmeter, windows-10, output

I'm running Jmeter 5.4.1 in Windows 10 machine in NON-GUI mode.

Im struggling with understanding the real difference between saving the output of a testrun in the .jtl file vs saving it as a csv file in the View results tree (or other listeners). They seem to do the same thing?

My goal is to save the complete response message bodies from all of the different samplers in either .jtl file or to another destination file (which I am pointing in the listeners section). So far I have not managed to get it to work as I would like to. I have read somewhere that I need to change the *user.properties* file to add the following lines:

jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv 
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true 
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=true 
jmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names=true

But I have to say Im not really sure why. Do I need to add anything more in any configuration file?
And also, what is the basic difference between jmeter.properties file and user.properties file. I read that you mostly need to change stuff in user.properties when you need to modify things?

Thanks for all help and advice

Answer (score 1):

As per https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config

> response_data is currently not supported for CSV output

There is no technical difference between the `jmeter.properties` and `user.properties` but in how they are supposed to be used.

From the `jmeter.properties` file:

```
#                      THIS FILE SHOULD NOT BE MODIFIED
#
# This avoids having to re-apply the modifications when upgrading JMeter
# Instead only user.properties should be modified:
# 1/ copy the property you want to modify to user.properties from jmeter.properties
# 2/ Change its value there
```

Answer (score 1):

As per [JMeter Wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles)

> **What are JTL files?**
> JMeter can create text files containing the results of a test run.
> These are normally called JTL files, as that is the default extension - but any extension can be used.

> **Types of JTL file**
> There are currently two types of JTL file:
> XML
> CSV (with and without header)
> The XML files can contain more types of information, but are considerably larger.

If you want the **full** information on the request/response you either need to convert the JMeter results file into **XML** format and specify what exactly you want to store:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.url=true
```

or add a separate [Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html) to save the data you need into a separate file because for example if you want to generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) - it can be done only from CSV files. More information: [How to Save Response Data in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-save-response-data-in-jmeter)

With regards to the difference between `jmeter.properties` and `user.properties` file - both are used for defining [JMeter Properties](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html), the order is as follows:

1. Properties passed via `-J` command line argument has the maximum priority
2. Properties defined in `user.properties` file take precedence over ones which live under `jmeter.properties`
3. It's recommended to perform any properties overrides either via `-J` arguments or via `user.properties` file or separate `.properties` file as it might cause issues/inconsistencies during upgrades to a newer version

See [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter) chapter for more details.